# C++11 atomic: is std::memory_order code portable?

Tags: c++, multithreading, portability, memory-model, stdatomic

In functions like `std::atomic::compare_exchange`, there's runtime parameters like `std::memory_order_release`, `std::memory_order_relaxed`.
(http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange)

I'm not sure is these memory order flags are guaranteed to exist in all kinds of CPU/architects, if some CPU don't support a flag, does this flag lead to crash or? Seems some of these flags are designed for intel Itanium, etc, not sure if `std::memory_order` related code is portable or not.

Would you give some suggestions?

Comment: If they are standard types (which they are) then a standard conforming compiler must provide them.

Comment: @NathanOliver not saying you are wrong; but, in some cases (didn't look up *this one*) the standard does make some things optional/implementation defined.. might be worth checking [the actual standards text](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf)..

Comment: [32.4] http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf can't see any exceptions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C++ standard does have the concept of so-called "freestanding" implementations, which can support a subset of the standard library. However, it also defines bare-minimum functionality that even a freestanding implementation must support. Within that list is the *entirety* of the `<atomic>` header.

So yes, implementations must support these.

However, that doesn't mean that a particular flag will do exactly and only what that flag describes. The flags represent the minimum memory barrier, the specific things that are guaranteed to be visible. The implementation could issue a full memory barrier even for flags that don't require it, if the hardware implementation doesn't have lower-tier memory barriers.

So you should write code against what the standard says, and let the compiler sort out the details. If it proves to be inefficient on a platform, you can inspect the assembly to see if you might be able to improve matters.

But to answer your main question, yes, atomic-based code is portable (modulo compiler bugs).

Comment: Part 2 of 2 in Herb Sutter's ["atomic<> Weapons: The C++ Memory Model and Modern Hardware"](https://herbsutter.com/2013/02/11/atomic-weapons-the-c-memory-model-and-modern-hardware/) talk goes into some detail about how some ISAs need to strengthen certain operations way past the required strength because the choices are either `relaxed` or a full barrier.  e.g. ARM notably can't do *just* a `mo_release` store, only relaxed or seq_cst.  https://godbolt.org/z/pYhsjz shows a release store compiling to the same asm as seq_cst (`stlr` which is a sequential-release).

Comment: @PeterCordes I view ack/rel as each asymmetric (past/future), local (act on a single atomic), high level C/C++ concepts that can conceivably be optimized at high level, which are quite diff from fences which are generally symmetric (AFAIK), act on every object, cannot be removed (except in trivial cases of repeated consecutive fences).

Comment: @curiousguy: we're talking about asm fence instructions like x86 `mfence` or ARM `dsb ish`, used to *implement* `x = 1` (seq_cst) or `int local = shared` (seq_cst load).  We're not talking about C++ `std::atomic_thread_fence`, although C++ -> asm mappings for fences might need to be stronger than you'd like, too.

Comment: BTW, to add to my first comment: AArch64 `stlr` apparently can't pass `ldar`.  It's not a full barrier on its own, but those two instructions can't StoreLoad reorder past each other, and other instructions can't reorder past them, so we do get sequential consistency from them, but with similar cost to x86 if you *only* do a seq-cst store or an acquire-load, not seq or rel store then seq or acq reload soon after.  (And unlike x86, seq-cst pure store doesn't need to flush the store buffer on the spot, only before the next acquire load).

Comment: @PeterCordes "_we're talking_ ..." Yes indeed: `atomic_thread_fence` w/ ack resp. rel is global (doesn't act on a single object) but it's asymmetric (past/future). OTOH `mfence` is symmetric: all future accesses are sequenced after all past accesses. The seq_cst or ack_rel `atomic_thread_fence` is symmetrically (ack/rel: it does both) asymmetric (past/future): all past relaxed loads become ack and all future relaxed stores become rel both being asym properties that affect both reads and writes but in the past resp. future.

Comment: @curiousguy: `atomic_thread_fence` [is a symmetric 2-way barrier](https://preshing.com/20131125/acquire-and-release-fences-dont-work-the-way-youd-expect/).  For example, a release *fence* is not just a release *operation*, otherwise it wouldn't stop 2 relaxed stores from reordering with each other if you put it between them.  But it does do that.

Comment: @PeterCordes You are playing with "words" (actually, concepts) here: a fence has a limited symmetry between two related stores. There is no symmetry if you allow for non atomic operations in your symmetry test.

Comment: @curiousguy: I'm not playing with words, I'm correcting a common misconception.  Go read Jeff Preshing's article I linked debunking what I think you're claiming / thinking.  Anyway, I don't know why you're making a big deal out of what exactly fences are in theory.  This answer is about how they're implemented in practice using asm barriers and blocking compile-time reordering.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201977/discussion-between-curiousguy-and-peter-cordes).

Answer (score 6):

In general, compilers are free to only provide the *strongest* memory guarantees regardless of what you ask for.

On some platforms, there are relaxed guarantees that are sufficient.  Not all platforms support these relaxed guarantees.  On those platforms, compilers must provide strictly stronger guarantees.

So they are portable, in that comforming compilers must provide that guarantee *or better* when you ask for a paticular guarantee.

Note that it isn't just the hardware that is of concern.  Certain optimizations and reorderings may be legal or not depending on what memory order guarantee you ask for.  I am unaware of any compiler that relies on that, but I am not a compiler expert.

Answer (score 0):

In practice, consume semantic is always strengthened to acquire by current compilers because it turned out to be very hard to implement safely without doing that.  Either:

- the architecture provides acquire on all loads, and then load consume does the same thing as load acquire which does the same as load relaxed: nothing special (like x86);
- the architecture requires an acquire barrier even on dependent accesses (very very rare, maybe only DEC Alpha): then the compiler will use an acquire barrier on consume;
- The ISA guarantees dependency ordering for loads in asm, but full acquire needs a barrier.  (This is what `consume` is trying to expose to the programmer). The compiler should provide you the benefit of avoiding the barrier with logical (not crazy) uses of consume

  - either the compiler tries to do that, but it's tricky and fails in some corner cases that the compiler back end optimizations break (the front end often does not communicate with its back end enough to avoid these just for consume);
  - or you don't trust the compiler, set optimization to zero, which doesn't even guarantee that no trivial optimization done implicitly by the back end will break consume (and make performance very bad);
  - or the compiler writers did not care about efficiency or knew they couldn't do a reliable job providing consume so they provide acquire instead, which is semantically correct but really less efficient, and not the intent of the standard.

(And C++'s consume semantic is crazy. It's one of the most inconsistent part of C++ which tells you a lot.)

Comment: This originally stated that "In practice, consume semantic is not portable."  That's incorrect; using it as specified in the standard works everywhere.  As the other answers explain, you don't always get as weak an operation as you were hoping for.  e.g. ARM can't do just release stores, only sequential-release (either with a barrier or ARMv8 `stlr`).  Unlike PowerPC or SPARC, it doesn't have a barrier that only blocks LoadStore + StoreStore without also draining the store buffer.  As you can see, a seq-cst and rel store compile the same for AArch64: https://godbolt.org/z/pYhsjz

Comment: Anyway, `consume` is crazy because the asm guarantees only guarantee actual data dependency ordering.  Control dependencies (branching on the load result) can break that, and compiler optimization normally has no concept of preserving data dependencies.  So yes, exposing that level of stuff in C++ is pretty hairy, and ultimately wasn't successful it seems.  At least not enough for compilers to actually implement consume as anything weaker than acquire).  I don't know why you'd call that "not portable"; it's acquire everywhere.

Comment: @PeterCordes "_crazy because the asm guarantees only_ ..." That isn't what I meant, but there is that. One issue is that consume should have been a type qualifier like const/volatile, but one that works for rvalues (so like const and volatile): `int consume + int*` should be `int* consume`, etc. "_compiler optimization normally has no concept of preserving data dependencies_" That's the issue w/ even simple optimizations (which could be avoided) but then there are global optimizations: if you have a singleton, can you consume read a ptr to it?

Comment: @PeterCordes I came across this: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0750r1.html The bibliography in itself seem worth reading it.

Comment: Interesting idea to have it be a type qualifier.  I guess that helps keep track of whether the dependency is intended to escape the function or not.  And thanks for the link; good to see that some work is happening on this.